# Can't get minicart value in product detail page

Tags: magento2

I add an item in mini-cart and I tried to get mini-cart value like `price, qty, and sku` in `Product Detail Page` and it show empty, but when I get mini-cart value in other page except `Product Detail Page` it show the value
anybody can help me how to get mini-cart value in `Product Detail Page`?

here's my code:

```
<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$cartlist = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
?>
<?php
foreach ($cartlist as $item) {
$productSku = $item->getSku();
$productQty = explode(".",$item->getQty());
$productPrice = explode(".",$item->getPrice());
$itemCart[] = "{item: "."'".$productSku."'".", "."price: ".$productPrice[0].", "."quantity: ".$productQty[0]."}";
$newitemCart = implode(", ",$itemCart);
}

?>
```

the code is in new phtml (I created a new phtml) file in `<myvendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/html/` Then I called the phtml in `default.xml` (`<myvendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/layout/`). Then when I get mini-cart value in other page except `Product Detail Page` it show the value but in `Product Detail Page` the mini-cart value is empty)

Answer (score 0):

```
$custom_cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
$custom_cart->getQuote()->getItemsQty();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).